# AnimatorObject Path

Tags: android, animation, path

I am trying to make an image to follow a defined path, but cant get the path to work.

I have this:

```
val path_um:Path = Path("m250 250c-1.2 0.4 -1.9 1.7 -1.5 2.9")
val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "translationX", "translationY", path_um)
```

How do I get this to work?
What am I missing?

---

UPDATE 12/3/2017

There is a type mismatch in the Path argument. It says its a string and not a path. I don't know how to convert to path.

This path is already inside a vetor, as a path, but I don't know how to make a path element move along another path. Any references on that?

Comment: animation.setDuration(); animation.setInterperation(); animation.start();

Comment: And, make sure you are animate "translationX" property or "x" property. the relative or absolute position, it looks like you should use absolute position, please refer: http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2015/02/objectanimator-to-animate-coordinates.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try to define it in the xml file. Its much more easy.  And your anomation didnt start